# laravel send mail after checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I need to send mail after checkbox checked here the code of this action,

this controller

```
foreach ($session->committee->members->whereIn('member_type_id', [1, 2]) as $member) {
            Mail::to($member->member->user_mail)
                ->queue(new NotifySessionAddingSubjects($member->member, Auth::user(), $session));
        }
```

this is blade

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline ">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" id="inlineCheckbox2" type="checkbox" name="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2" @if(old('inlineCheckbox2')) checked @endif checked>
                                            <br>
                                            <label class="form-check-label text-dark p-1" for="inlineCheckbox2">إرسال بريد إلكتروني</label>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: Get the value of your checkbox from the request: `$request->checkbox`. And that's it.

Comment: Thanks bro, i'I'll try it 